# server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I need to use a third party WCF service. I have configured the required certificate on my certificate store however I am getting following exception when calling the WCF service.

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://XXXX.com/AHSharedServices/CustomerServiceJAXWSController. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

I checked with the service vendor and they said everything is good from their end and other people are using this service already. They mentioned that when a request comes from my IP Address their service is not receiving the certificate content. They monitored this into the wireshark and the certificate's length is 0

Following is the my client configuration. Am I missing anything here?

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <configuration>
              <startup>
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
              </startup>
              <system.diagnostics>
                <sources>
                  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
                    <listeners>
                      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                      </add>
                      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                      </add>
                    </listeners>
                  </source>
                </sources>
                <sharedListeners>
                  <add initializeData="D:\Log\MessageLog.svclog"
                    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                    name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                    <filter type="" />
                  </add>
                </sharedListeners>
                <trace autoflush="true" />
              </system.diagnostics>
              <system.serviceModel>
                <behaviors>
                  <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
                      <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="XXX.XX.com" storeName="AddressBook"
                          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate>
                          <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                        </serviceCertificate>
                      </clientCredentials>
                    </behavior>
                  </endpointBehaviors>
                </behaviors>
                <bindings>
                  <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="wsBinding">
                      <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                      </security>
                    </binding>
                  </wsHttpBinding>
                </bindings>
                <client>
                  <endpoint address="https://XXXX.com/AHSharedServices/CustomerServiceJAXWSController"
                    behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="wsBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.CustomerServiceJAXWSController"
                    name="testService" />
                </client>
                <diagnostics>
                  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
                    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logKnownPii="true"  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"/>
                </diagnostics>
              </system.serviceModel>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: is the certificate valid or a self signed certificate?

Comment: yes the certificate is valid one.

Comment: and the client must have a valid certificate too? A few time ago I implemented a similar solution but the only the wcf server needed a valid certificate, why do you need the client to have a valid certificate too?

Comment: Well, client needs to have the valid certificate to allow server to authenticate the request!

Comment: I got it working currently with HttpWebRequest class. I had to generate PFX file out of CRT and KEY (a certificate with embedded private key). I am still struggling to get it working on WCF

Answer (score 4):

I once received this error because my client was using TLS 1.0 instead of TLS 1.2.
Assuming that you have all of the correct SSL ciphers installed, you could attempt to alter your request to use TLS 1.2 instead. In .NET, you'd add this after your client is defined:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Once I switched to TLS 1.2, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I generated the PFX (certificate with private key attached) out of .CRT and .KEY and imported it to the certificate store and that fixed the issue I had.

Comment: Do you mean you created the pfx from the server .crt and .key?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code before send request to server:

```cs
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};
```